# How to animate point in right direction on update chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have two problems with chartjs.

1. I test two lib's chartjs and amCharts 5. And I can't get nice effect animation when added data, and update on chartjs.

This is a example chartjs:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/7syc5hfr/7`
```

And perfect working amCharts 5:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/deicidemilan/uj7d4tx9/5
```

So when chartjs update line is drawn from bottom to last dot, on amCharts 5 last line update smooth and nice.

2. When new data is update on amCharts 5 xAxis, grid folow animation. On chartjs just blink to needed position when last line is drawn.

Is it possible to get this on chartjs?

[Animation first problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojoqA.png)

Thanks in advance,
Milan

Comment: No m8 it does not. I draw how animation is supposed to work, and I edit my question with picture. https://i.ibb.co/5rtmnZq/Animation.png

Comment: Since you are testing both libs, what is stopping you from using amcharts if that doesn't have problems?

Comment: @LeeLenalee AmChart have a Memory Footprint leak in lib on some modules. You can see on this link https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts5/issues/125 I need for my app to work stable 24/7.

Comment: @MilanDjekic have a look at the `y: {from: ...}` setup in this example: [Chart.js Progressive Line](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.1/samples/animations/progressive-line.html) -- based on what you describe, I expect some part of that will address your question.

Comment: @Joshua Voskamp I will take a look, and test this functionality. Then I will let you know if it satisfies what I am looking for.

Comment: @Joshua Voskamp I read more about Chart.js docs, all docs animations are related to initial drawings of the chart, but I only need for the chart updates from the last dot to the next similar to the picture I drew, and I need the grids to move smooth as on amCharts. I feel this is very doable with chatr.js but can't figure it out how. I can draw more clearer picture if it helps.

Comment: It is possible to have smooth going grid, you can take a look at the streaming plugin on how they did it: https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/latest/samples/charts/line-horizontal.html

Comment: @LeeLenalee Thank you this is a perfect solution for smooth going grid (my 2nd problem). I didn't think in direction of plugins at all. This help even to hide next line so animation of upcoming line is nice. Do you know is there a plugin for my 1st problem?